# Can't Reach ViewModel From Within ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, listbox

I have a ViewModel set as the highest level DataContext for my wpf application but I can't seem to access it when I jump into a ListBox as the new DataContext is the element of the list. A simple example is below.

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<StackPanel>
    <!--1D List-->
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding my_list}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!--Individual Elements-->
                <TetxBlock Text="{Binding ViewModel_DisplayString}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

That example won't actually work when it comes to the button click as the ViewModel_ClickFunction isn't on the items within the class.

So is there anyway for me to do {Binding parent.selected_item} or something like that? I just need to be able to access the ViewModel from within the ListBox.

Comment: You better use `Command` instead. I don't think you cannot access the handler. It's simply part of code behind. Normally when I define some handler, I just type its name in XAML code, then right click on it and select *Navigate to Event Handler*.

Comment: Ah true enough. I've updated the question to be more clear about what's being asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DataContext` inside `ItemTemplate` is actually the item itself. So in this case you have to use `RelativeSource` to walk up the visual tree (to the `ListBox`) and change the `Path` to `DataContext.ViewModel_DisplayString`:

```
 <TetxBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.ViewModel_DisplayString,
                         RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}"/>
```